# Explanation of fields in Get-VM command Hyper-V

Tags: windows, powershell, hyper-v

I have a Hyper-V machine with virtual machines running on it. Recently I tried some PowerShell scripts on it. The script is

```
Get-Vm  | sort Name |
    select Name, Uptime, @{N="MemoryMB";E={$_.MemoryAssigned/1MB}},
        ProcessorCount, Status, @{N="MemoryMaxMB";E={$_.MemoryMaximum/1MB}}
```

I have doubts on few of the fields. When I am comparing it with machines I guess `MemoryAssigned` is the RAM of the machine where as is there any way by which I can get RAM allocated for turned off machines and also the Hard Disk details of each?

Comment: `Get-Vm | Get-Member`

Answer (score 1):

There is no Memory allocated to a Virtual Machine that is not running.

Get-Vm brings back a `Selected.Microsoft.HyperV.PowerShell.VirtualMachine` object.

If you use `Get-Member` as suggested by Ansgar Wiechers, you will see a property called HardDrives which has some information about your hard disks. one of which is the path which we can use:

```
(Get-VM).HardDrives | foreach {Get-Vhd -Path $_.Path}
```